# Having trouble creating xls file in Visual Studio using C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to fix someone else's code in creating an Excel file from data on a website. We have the data up, and the user can hide or show certain parts of it by using different check boxes and such on the site. Once the user has what they want displayed, we have an option to export it to an excel file. Everything works as it should, until the file is opened. When opening the file, the error:

> The file you are trying to open, 'filename.xls', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?

Now, the file still opens up if clicked yes, and the data is formatted just fine. However, we would like for this error to disappear, as it is not very user friendly or clean-looking. Here is the code used to export:

```
        // perform export
        System.Web.HttpResponse objResponse = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        objResponse.Clear();
        objResponse.Charset = "";
        objResponse.Buffer = true;
        objResponse.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "filename.xls"));
        objResponse.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        System.IO.StringWriter objStringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter objHTMLWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter);
        m_objDataTable.RenderControl(objHTMLWriter);
        objResponse.Write(objStringWriter);
        objResponse.End();
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of excel?  You might need to use an xlsx file extension.

Comment: So, you're just rendering your DataTable control directly to the HtmlTextWriter? That's going to be part of the problem. Excel knows how to display documents like you're creating, but it's always going to warn you, because it's not a native Excel file. You'd have to actually create a proper Excel document, whether through Interop or some other mechanism to get rid of that error.

Comment: Running Excel 2010. I've tried using the xlsx extension, but then the error pops up as well, and won't even let me open up the file at all.

Yeah, I realize it's not creating a native excel document this way. I was hoping that there is a workaround, however. The person who made the code won't be back for a week, and I don't really want to rewrite the entire program.

Comment: You could probably save it as a CSV file (which is plaintext) and avoid the file type mismatch.

Comment: Using the csv extension does avoid the file type mismatch, but it will display everything as plaintext, of course. Unfortunately, that makes the data quite ugly and hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the first step is to look at the resulting file in a text only editor to figure out what is being output.
The XLS extension does not support compression, that would be XLSX.
The XLS extension does support HTML (extremely slow), tab delimited data (much faster), and native Excel spreadsheets.
A quick look should tell you what is being output.
Personal preference is tab delimited text only or comma delimited csv depending on what is in the data.
Since you're using the Excel Object, I suspect that the output would be in native Excel but the HTMLTextWriter tells me that it is being output as a table. Looking at it as text will tell if you have a valid HTML or Excel file or a mix of both.

**Edit** The next trick is change the extension to HTML and open it in a browser. It should show a visible glitch in the data if it has an error. The HTML format doesn't do well if the data contains HTML.
The tab delimited output will handle the HTML correctly but all tabs must be changed to space and the CSV doesn't do well with complex strings.
I haven't done a native export to XLS in more than 10 years and that was because I wanted to add calculations to the cells. (It was in VB6)

Comment: Opening the file in notepad reveals that it is just html text.